# Prove that $f(x) = 4 - 15x$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Need help showing this.

Show that the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}:$ defined by  $f(x) = 4 - 15x$ is continuous at every point $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Judging by the votes on my comment, several answers should be coming up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I try to describe one way of thinking about this. The actual proof is written in blue, the rest is just guidance. I did it with a lot of detail, to the point where it might actually confuse you, so beware.

---

*You are being asked to prove that*
$$\forall c\in \mathbb R\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right).$$

*(This is just the definition, there is nothing to it).*

*(In words: given a real number $c$ and a positive real $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ with the property that for all real numbers $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, it holds that $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$)*.

*(Since this is a universal statement, you begin by taking an arbitrary $c\in \mathbb R$.)*

$\color{blue}{\text{Let $c\in \mathbb R$.}}$

*(Now you wish to prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right)$. This again is a universal statement, so take an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$).*

$\color{blue}{\text{Let $\varepsilon >0$.}}$

*(Now you wish to prove that* $\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right)$.

*(In words: there exists a positive real number $\delta$ with the property that for all real numbers $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$)*.

*This is an existential statement, one way to do it is to find $\delta >0$ such that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right)$. This is what I suggest you do, find a $\delta$ that works). To do this, I suggest the thought of process below which I do in a scratch work box).*

---

*Scratch work:* To prove that $\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right)$, we can begin by assuming we already have such $\delta$ (just to see what happens).

So let $\delta>0$ be such that $\forall x\in \mathbb R(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon)$ and take an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb R$.

We have the conditional statement $|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$.

Now it's useful to look at the consequent to see what kind of restrictions we need to impose on $\delta$ for this conditional statement to hold. It is almost always necessary to relate the consequent with the inequality in the antecedent ($|x-c|<\delta$).

The following holds: $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|=15|x-c|$. One notices that in the consequent occurs the number $|x-c|$ which also occurs in the antecedent, thus relating the consequent to the antecedent. Recalling that $|x-c|<\delta$ one gets $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|=15|x-c|<15\delta$
. This suggest that letting $\delta$ be such that $15\delta =\varepsilon$ (or equivalently $\delta=\dfrac \varepsilon {15}$) should work.

Now the scratch work is abandoned and we get back to the proof.

---

$\color{blue}{\text{Choose $\delta =\dfrac{\varepsilon}{15}$.}}$

*(You wish to prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon\right)$. It is a universal statement so you should take $x\in \mathbb R$ arbitrarily).*

$\color{blue}{\text{Let $x\in \mathbb R$.}}$

*(Now you want to prove the conditional statement $|x-c|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$. In words: if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$). The most forward way to do this is to assume the antecedent and try to prove the consequent).*

$\color{blue}{\text{Suppose $|x-c|<\delta$.}}$

*(Now you want to prove that $|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|<\varepsilon$).*

$\color{blue}{\text{One has}}$

$$\color{blue}{\text{$\begin{align}|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|&=|4-15x-4+15c|\\ &=|-15x+15c|\\ &=15|-x+c|\\ &=15|x-c|<\varepsilon .\end{align}$}}$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Since $|x-c|<\delta$ and $\delta =\dfrac {\varepsilon}{15}$ it follows that}}$ $$\color{blue}{|(4-15x)-(4-15c)|=15|x-c|<15\delta=15\dfrac{\varepsilon}{15}=\varepsilon.\,\,\square}$$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that out! I'll have to take the time to study the description properly.

Comment: @Finance No worries, but I suggest you only accept an answer after you understand it. Don't feel forced to accept mine. You should accept whatever answer was more helpful to you.

Comment: This is the proof of continuinty at every point right, what if the question asks for a point, e.g continuous at x = 0?

Comment: @Finance then everything is similar, but you have $0$ instead of $c$ and you don't quantify $c$. That is, you prove $$\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(|x-0|<\delta \implies |(4-15x)-(4-15\cdot 0)|<\varepsilon\right).$$ Then the proof is the same, but it starts at "Let $\varepsilon >0$" instead.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind, it would be really helpful if under some of the long definitions involving the symbols and greek letters, you could also write (maybe in red or something) in words what it means also (I'm still learning the symbols so constantly referring to my notes just to read it makes it harder to understand.)

Comment: Do you mean writing "For all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ ..." or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, it's just a little confusing to read at the moment.

Comment: @Finance I wrote some of the formulas by words. I hope this is is what you were looking for.

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in \Bbb R$ be any point, to show that it is continuous at point $a$,

$$|f(x) - f(a)|< \epsilon  \\  \mathrm{or, } |4 - 15x - a + 15a| < \epsilon \\  \mathrm{or, }  15 |x-a| < \epsilon$$

Choose your $\delta = \epsilon / 15$.

The $\epsilon-\delta $ definition of continuity says that you need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some  $\delta > 0$ such that , $ |x-a|< \delta  \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon $. So by choosing $\delta  = \frac \epsilon {15}$ we showed the existence of such delta.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more complete proof.

Comment: "More complete" ? ...

Comment: I should have said "completed", I'll be using this as a template for further problems so it would be nice to have the full proof.

Comment: @BertrandR I would say this answer definitely can be improved and that's why I didn't up vote it. This likely is the first example of this kind the OP has ran into. It's not surprising that this isn't enough. **Edit:** I wouldn't down vote it, though.

Comment: I downvoted it. This answer is not helpful and, as a matter of fact, is incomplete. sorry

Comment: @GitGud I guess I see what you mean, I assumed that the OP could derive the full proof from the idea, but I probably underestimate the difficulty of the question for a first encounter. Edit : I don't think it deserves a downvote also.

Comment: Everyone, okay ... is the answer a bit better?

Comment: @Santosh Your wording is wrong here "there exists some $\delta >0$ such that for every $\varepsilon >0$..." You're swapping the quantifiers. It should be "for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$..."

Comment: @GitGud okay okay ... i'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Let $\epsilon  > 0 $ be given. To show continuity of $f(x)$ ar $c$, by definition, we have to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-c|< \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(c) | < \epsilon $. So, our goal is to find $\delta $ that works. Let's see,

$$ |f(x) - f(c)| = | 4 - 15x - (c - 15c) | = |4 - 15x - 4 + 15c| = 15|x-c| $$

The last term if less than $\epsilon $ if and only if $ \delta = \frac{ \epsilon }{15} $

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition:
   $f$ is continuous at point $c$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ $$| x - c | < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - f(c) | < \varepsilon. \,$$
2. We'll try to find $\delta$ which will be good enough: $$\varepsilon>|f(x)-f(c)|=|4-15x-4+15c|=15|x-c|.$$ We know that $|x-c|$ should be less than $\delta$ so we can use $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{15}$.
3. And now check the definition:
   let $c$ be arbitrary, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we will use $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{15}>0$.
   Now, for all $x$ $$| x - c | < \delta \Rightarrow |x-c|<\frac{\varepsilon}{15} \Rightarrow 15|x-c|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |15c - 15x|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |4-15x-4+15c|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$$ And that's what we wanted to prove.

It is pretty much like the other answers, so nothing new, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the proof of continuinty at every point right, what if the question asks for a point, e.g continuous at x = 0?

Comment: This is the proof for point $c$. For your function you may let $c$ be any (your function is obviously continuous ay every point at all), but if you want continuity at $0$ you may just replace $c$ with $0$ everywhere.